# Same output about Pointers in C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following is a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
   int i,n=10;
   double *a;
   a = (double *)calloc(n,sizeof(double));
   if (!a){
       printf("Allocating error!\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   for (i=0;i<10;i++){
       printf("%f\n",*a++); /*Print 1*/
       printf("%f\n",a++);  /*Print 2*/
       printf("%f\n",a[i]); /*Print 3*/
   }
}
```

Note: the three print lines were tested separately, for instance, run `printf("%f\n",*a++); /*Print 1*/` and let the other two print lines as comment lines.

My question is: why three different print lines have the same output? My understanding is Print 2 and 3 have the same meaning, but they're address... Print 1 has a dereference sign (*) so it's the number in double-type. I'm confused, can anybody give a clear explanation?

Attach compilation message:

```
warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
        printf("%f\n",a++);  /*Print 2*/
```

But the weird thing is: if I directly execute the code rather than debug it first, there's no mistake and all of them output the correct results (ten 0.000000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly compile your program with warnings enabled flags as below, it may tell you number of things.

```
gcc -g -O -Wall test.c
```

Here is the explanation .

```
int  main()
{
        int i,n=10;
        double *a;
        a = (double *)calloc(n,sizeof(*a));/* use sizeof(*a) instead of sizeof(double) */
        if (!a){
                printf("Allocating error!\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        for (i=0;i<10;i++)
                printf("%lf\n",*a++); /* use %lf as a is of double ptr type
                                        it prints 0.00 everytimes not 1 as calloc zeroed 
                                        whole memory */

        /* when loop fails where a points ? */
        printf("%p\n",a++);  /* it prints address and use %p instead of %f */
        printf("%lf\n",a[i]); /* it results in undefined behaviour 
                                as you are trying to access out of boundry like a[11] 
                                which you didn't allocated */

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%f` is fine for formatting a `double` argument in `printf`. It is defined to take a `double` value.

Comment: but if usage of `%f` with `*a` will print only data in first `4 byte(GCC)` , correct me if I'm  wrong.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the three print lines were tested separately, for instance, run `printf("%f\n",*a++); /*Print 1*/` and let the other two print lines as comment lines.

Comment: @achal: You are quite wrong. In `printf("%f\n",*a++)`, `a` points to a double. The pointer is incremented, and the initially pointed-to `double` is retrieved. That `double` is passed to `printf`. The `f` conversion specifier fot `printf` is **defined in the C standard** to take a `double` argument. It does so and converts the `double` value. (`scanf` is defined to take a pointer to `float` for `%f` and a pointer to `double` for `%lf`. For `printf`, they are both `double`.)

Comment: Thanks @EricPostpischil I thought for both `printf` and `scanf` it works as same. this is very informative. I corrected myself.

Answer (score 0):

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to print `double*` as `double` on each iteration with your call `printf("%f\n",a++);` and then again by attempting to access values beyond the end of your allocated block of memory on your call to `printf ("  %f\n", a[i]);` beginning when `i = 3` and for each subsequent iteration of your `for` loop.

**Why are weird things happening?**

When you declare `double *a;`, `a` is a *pointer to double*, not a `double` itself. What is a pointer? A pointer is simply a variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. When you attempt to call `printf("%f\n",a++);` you are attempting to print the pointer, not the value at the address held by the pointer (which you obtain by *dereferencing* the pointer with the unary `'*'` operator, e.g. `*a`).

This is undefined behavior as described in [C11 §7.21.6.1(p2 & p9) The fprintf function - insufficient arguments, or incorrect type.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)

Next, your attempt to both loop over each element with a `for` loop while incrementing the pointer within the loop causes you to attempt to read values beyond the end of your allocated block beginning with `i = 3`.

When you allocate memory for `a` with `a = calloc (n, sizeof(double));` (**note:** See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)), you allocate `n` times `sizeof(double)` bytes initialized to all zero by using `calloc`. (80-bytes on most modern desktops). You allocate space for `10 doubles` that can be access through indexes:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ..\ ..| 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
```

One of the promises you make to the compiler when you allocate memory, is a promise you will only attempt to write or access values within the block, (you can reference the byte past the last value, but cannot attempt to read or write at that or any other address outside of your allocated block.

When you begin your loop, `a` holds the address to the beginning of the block of allocated memory, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ..\ ..| 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
^
a
```

On  your first call to `printf("%f\n",*a++);`, a **side-effect** of the post-increment operator (e.g. `a++`) is that the pointer `a` is advance by `sizeof *a` bytes (or one `double`). That is the entire basis of *pointer arithmetic*. So after your call to `printf("%f\n",*a++);`, `a` points to the second element, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ..\ ..| 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
    ^
    a
```

Your next call to `printf("%f\n",a++);` invokes *Undefined Behavior* and then again advances the pointer by use of the post increment operator leaving `a` pointing to the third-element, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ..\ ..| 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+
        ^
        a
```

You then call `printf("%f\n",a[i]);` which prints the third-element, and you `for` loop increments `i = 1`, and then cycle repeats, except with each increment, when you call `printf("%f\n",a[i]);`, you reference the **current value of `a` plus the index**. Meaning `a[i]` is just array-index notation that is the equivalent of `*(a + i)` in pointer notation.

Each iteration within your `for` loop, you advance where `a` points by 16-bytes (or by two `double` values) by your use of `a++` within the loop. On your 4th iteration (where `i = 3`), immediately prior to your call to `printf("%f\n",a[i]);`, `a` points to one-before the last element of your allocated block, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ..\ ..| 8 | 9 |  you don't own this   |
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                            ^           ^
                            a         a[3]
```

So when you attempt to print with `a[3]` (e.g. `*(a + 3)`) you are attempting to print a value from an address 8-bytes (or one `double`) **past the end of your allocated block**. By the end of the next iteration `a` no longer points anywhere within the your allocated block of memory, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ..\ ..| 8 | 9 |  you don't own this   |
+---+---+---+---+---+-  /  -+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                    ^
                                    a
```

Further, you have lost the ability to `free(a)`, because you have failed to preserve a pointer to the beginning of the block of memory you have allocated. If you allocate `a = calloc (n, sizeof(double));`, never increment `a` itself without first saving a copy of the beginning address first. Generally you won't iterate `a`, but instead a second pointer, such as `double *p = a;`, then you can `p++` all you like and still have the ability to `free(a);` because `a` still points to the beginning of the allocated block of memory. In your case, attempting to `free(a)` will likely cause an immediate crash.

When you invoke *Undefined Behavior*, the behavior of your code can do anything from appear to act correctly to SegFault'ing. (what it will do is *undefined*). It is ill-formed code. So don't break your promise with the compiler, don't attempt to read or write to address outside the allocated block of memory.

Lastly, the proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/). `void main` is an incorrect anachronism in virtually all systems, and all standard compliant systems.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: As stated in the question, the executed code contains only one of the displayed `printf` statements at a time. There is no overrun of the allocated storage. The only error is passing a pointer for `%f`. This statement was edited into the question over two hours before you answered.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, passing a pointer when using the `%f` conversion specifier for `printf` has behavior not defined by the C standard.

The reason it printed zero in your test is likely because the register where a `double` argument should have been passed contained zero. Many processors have separate registers for integer values and for floating-point values. When `printf` is printing a `double` value, it takes the value from the register designated for passing a floating-point argument. Since you passed a pointer, its value was put into the register designated for passing an integer-type argument, and the floating-point register was not changed. Since your program did not contain any actual floating-point operations, that register may have not been used at all in the program, so it still contained the zero that the operating system initialized it to when starting your process. That zero was printed.